# Compute the PVM (Projection Valued Measure) of Parity Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

This question is duplicate of the question [Find projection-valued measure associated with parity operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078915/find-projection-valued-measure-associated-with-parity-operator).\

But in that question @Jacky Chong does not state how he found the operator
\begin{align}
P_\pi(\lambda) =P_{\pi}((-\infty,\lambda]) =\delta(\lambda-1)P_\text{even}+\delta(\lambda+1)P_\text{odd}
\end{align}

Also we know that $P(R)=Id \enspace$ or we should have $P(\lambda_1)\leq P(\lambda_2)$  for  $\lambda_1 < \lambda _2$ but if we put 2 and 1 into the $P_{\pi}$ we get $0:L^2\rightarrow L^2$ and $P_{even}$ resp.

My question is could someone explain me how to find $P_{\pi}$ explicitly using maybe Stieltjes inversion formula or something else

**Notes:**
**(1)** I need 50 reps to comment on the problem i linked 
**(2)** I already found the spectrum and resolvent of parity operator.They're  $$\sigma(\Pi)=\{1,-1\} \enspace R_{\Pi}(z)=\frac{\Pi+zI}{1-z^2}$$
**(3)** This is Problem 3.2 from *Teschl G. - Mathematical methods in quantum mechanics*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply the standard way of writing a finite sum as an integral relative to a corresponding atomic measure. In particular: if the operator in question can be written as a countable sum
$$
A = \sum_i \lambda_i P_i
$$
(with the $P_i$ equal to spectral projectors and hence mutually orthogonal and "complete"), then the measure associated with $A$ can be written as
$$
P_A(\lambda) = \sum_i \delta(\lambda - \lambda_i)P_i.
$$
To see that this works, it suffices to show that for a Borel function $f$, $f(A)$ is indeed equal to $\int_{\Bbb R} f(\lambda) \,dP_{A}(\lambda)$. In other words, this is simply a consequence of the fact that
$$
f\left(\sum_i \lambda_i P_i\right) = \sum_i f(\lambda_i) P_i.
$$

Comment: First thank you for your answer.So by sayig "spectral projectors" what you mean is their sum is identity like if all the $\lambda_i=1$ and by making some of the $\lambda_i=0$ or something else we get $A$.In our case we have $P_{even}$ and $P_{odd}$ and their $\lambda$'s 1 and -1 resp. Also $\delta$ is dirac-delta right?It is not heaviside or whatever the name it is.Could you explain why it suffices to show that $f(A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(\lambda)dP_A(\lambda)$ because it forms a $C*$ homomorphism ? but there could be some other things that might be $C*$ homo without being PVM.

Comment: and i wrote an example that if we had $\lambda_2=2$ we get $0$ map but we should have had a map that extends $P_{even}$.Maybe i'm understanding it wrong but im confused little bit :D.Also sorry for late return

Comment: For your first comment: all your statements are correct. The precise answer to why it suffices depends on what exactly it means for a projection valued measure to be "associated with" an operator. I'm rusty with all this and don't have a reference on hand; it would be helpful if you could consult your textbook or notes for how exactly this is defined.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying about your example

Comment: i kind of get it now. I was confusing identity function and 1 function.Thanks for your answers anyway